# What would the regex be to detect this string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to determine if a given string has the sequence `dash-alpha-alpha-dash`.

Example strings:

```
114888-ZV-209897
409-II-224858
86296-MO-184080
2459-ND-217906
```

What would be the the regex to determine that?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, FWIW.

Comment: By "alpha", do you mean uppercase ASCII letters? I.e., no such weird stuff as `Ö` or `É`?

Comment: This is a very elementary question. Did you search for an answer? What have you tried? What did you get as results?

Comment: @theTinMan If there's a duplicate question here on SO, feel free to mark this as such and redirect to the duplicate. I didn't find it, but it's not exactly easy to search for this thing.

Comment: It's easy to figure out reading the documentation. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if subject =~ /-[A-Z]{2}-/
    # Successful match
else
    # Match attempt failed
end
```

That `[A-Z]` thingy is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: Thanks TIm, this is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple pattern:

```
/-[A-Z]{2}-/
```

will do it.

Your regex is available at: http://rubular.com/r/6hn8BLc7rF

For instance:

```
"114888-ZV-209897"[/-[A-Z]{2}-/]
=> "-ZV-"
```

So use:

```
if  "114888-ZV-209897"[/-[A-Z]{2}-/] ...
```